# How to let img go under text when resizing screen?

Tags: html, css

I want to put an image under a text when it resizes, like when your on your phone or iPad, because the image is to big to show to the right of it when its resized.

I tried using flexbox, but I am kind of new to html and CSS so I don't know how to solve this one, there is also a button under the text that's to the left, but I also want, that when the screen rezises, that the button goes under the text and stays in the middle

```css
.textwithnav1 {
  display: flex;
  background-color: gold;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid white 2px;
}
.container-text2 {
  background-color: #d4d4d4;
  height: auto;
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.783);
  border: solid 2px white;
  align-items: center;
  width: auto;
  margin: 15px;
}

.text22 h1 {
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-family: "roboto";
  font-size: 38px;
  text-align: center;
}
.text22 h1 span {
  border-bottom: solid 3px rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.text22 p {
  margin-top: 20px;
  font-family: "roboto";
  font-size: 22px;
  line-height: 32px;
  text-align: center;
}
/* button onze prjecten home page */
.button22 button {
  border: 1px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
  background: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: "roboto";
  color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.783);
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.5s;
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
.button22 button:hover {
  color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
  transform: scale(1.1);
  background-color: #979797;
}

/* onze prjecten foto */
.image22 {
  background-color: gold;
}
.image22 img {
  width: 800px;
  height: auto;
  margin: 15px;
  border: solid rgb(255, 255, 255) 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textwithnav1">
  <div class="container-text2">
    <div class="text22">
      <h1><span>Onze Project</span>en</h1>
      <p>
        Wij zijn aan hebben mogen bijdragen. Van het plaatsen
        van complete staalconstructies tot het bouwen van bruggen en het
        assisteren bij grootschalige bouwprojecten: wij hebben de juiste
        kranen en het juiste team om elk project tot een succes te maken.<br /><br />
        Wij staan bekend om onze flexibiliteit, betrouwbaarheid en
        vakmanschap en streven erverhuur op maat.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="button22">
      <button>Onze Projecten</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image22"><img src="https://picsum.photos/200/300" /></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe these links help: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox_responsive.asp https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_grid.asp

Comment: try the "order" property in css on the parent element "textwithnav1" e.g .textwithnav1{order: 1}

Answer (score 0):

### Add flex-wrap to the flex box:

```css
.textwithnav1 {
  display: flex;
flex-wrap: wrap;
  background-color: gold;
  justify-content: space-between;
  border: solid white 2px;
}
```